# Simple CSS/HTML - Nested Elements

Tags: html, css

https://i.stack.imgur.com/pKdrK.png

As you can see from this image, I have tried to create a header  with a div on top of it that is the main title of the page. I have looked everywhere and I can't figure out how to get the title on the top of the header, this may be very simple but I'm not sure.

p.s. The title is the small red bit that can barely be seen.

CSS

```
#title {
   font-family:Bebas;
   font-size:20px;
   font-weight:bold;
   border:5px groove #ff0022;
   color:#00D0FF;
   background-color:#ff0022;
   position:relative;
   margin-left:10px;
   margin-top:10px;
}
#banner {
       border:1px solid #4A4A4A;
       width:1903;
       height:110;
       background-color:#4A4A4A;
       margin-left:0px;
       position:absolute;
       top:-10px;
       border-radius:15px;
}
a:visited {

          text-decoration:none;
}
```

HTML

```
<head>
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="todd.css"/>
<title>Todd's Website</title>

</head>

<body>
     <a href="file:///C:/Users/Todd/Desktop/todd.html">
        <h1>
            <div id="title">Todd's Awesome Website!
                <div id="banner">




                </div>
            </div>
        </h1>
     </a> 
</body>



</html>
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ToddStyles/ET8nh/)

Comment: Please provide your code, preferably on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/).

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/ToddStyles/ET8nh/  This is all the coding so far, I have only just started so there is not much.

Comment: Your jsfiddle looks fine, at least in Firefox 20 and Chromium 25.

Comment: Looks fine on chrome

Answer (score 1):

You should put your divs outside of your h1 tag, and have the title id on the h1 tag. Also, you should put your a tag inside of your h1 tag:

```
<div>
  <div id="banner">
    <h1 id="title">
      <a href="file:///C:/Users/Todd/Desktop/todd.html">
        Todd's Awesome Website!
      </a>
    </h1>
  </div>
</div>
```

Hopefully this achieves the result you are looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Why wouldn't you simply put the title inside the banner? You can apply all your style directly to the H1

Comment: HTML should "be as semantic as possible". The <h1> element is specific to font styling, where as the <div> element is structural.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to move the title inside the banner, you can use `z-index: 10;`. That should make it show.